# ASP.NET Introduction of repository pattern causing 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository

I started to implement the repository pattern into my ASP.NET application, However in doing so attempting to run the Actions on the view I have implemented the pattern for, I get 'EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.'. This does not happen on the application when I haven't implemented the repository.

**MeetRepository.cs**

```
using MVCWebAssignment1.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCWebAssignment1.DAL
{
    public class MeetRepository : IMeetRepository
    {
        private readonly MeetContext _context;
        
        public MeetRepository(MeetContext meetContext)
        {
            _context = meetContext;
        }
        public IList<Meet> GetMeets()
        {
            return _context.Meets.ToList();
        }

        public Meet GetMeetById(int id)
        {
            return _context.Meets.Find(id);
        }

        public void InsertMeet(Meet meet)
        {
            _context.Meets.Add(meet);
        }

        public void DeleteMeet(int id)
        {
            Meet meet = _context.Meets.Find(id);
            _context.Meets.Remove(meet);
        }

        public void UpdateMeet(Meet meet)
        {
            _context.Entry(meet).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        
        public void Save()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        private bool disposed = false;
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if(!this.disposed)
            {
                if(disposing)
                {
                    _context.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

**IMeetRepository,cs**

```
using MVCWebAssignment1.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCWebAssignment1.DAL
{
    public interface IMeetRepository : IDisposable
    {
        IList<Meet> GetMeets();
        Meet GetMeetById(int id);
        void InsertMeet(Meet meet);
        void DeleteMeet(int id);
        void UpdateMeet(Meet meet);
        void Save();
    }
}
```

**MeetContext.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using MVCWebAssignment1.Models;

namespace MVCWebAssignment1.DAL
{
    public class MeetContext : DbContext
    {
        public MeetContext(): base("name=DefaultConnection"){}
        public DbSet<Meet> Meets { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

**MeetController.cs (Method flagging the issue)**

```
    public class MeetController : Controller
    {
        //private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        private IMeetRepository _meetRepository;

        public MeetController()
        {
            _meetRepository = new MeetRepository(new MeetContext());
        }

        // GET: Meet
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_meetRepository.GetMeets());
        }
    }
```

In summary, I can't identify why utilising the repository pattern would start to create issues with identity's default files, When the classes I've introduced don't utilise identity components.

Guidance much appreciated!

Comment: ***Standard note*** : The *repository pattern* over EF will cause you a lot of problems now and into the future, and is doing nothing other than adding a pointless extra layer of abstraction for usually no good reason. This pattern was more important before the use of full featured ORMs, yet unfortunately still gets promoted a lot by teachers and older blogs, though is shunned by the wider community and professional teams unless there is a specific use case.

Comment: On a side note, the code you have supplied and the repository is likely nothing to do with the actual error you are getting. You could prove this by just calling `return View(_context.Meets.ToList());`

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks for the response! In all honestly I was only looking to introduce it as further 'separation of concerns' for a highly ambiguous section on an assignment mark scheme. 

On further testing change the Pattern to accept the standard ApplicationDbContext scaffolded by ASP.NET + Identity, seemed to allow it to work, but naturally i believe this bypasses the repository pattern.

Also I must stress _context.Meets.ToList()) Worked completely prior to the introduction of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue after a further bit of experimenting. I solved it by inheriting from IdentityDbContect on my repository context.

**MeetContext.cs**

```
 public class MeetContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public MeetContext(): base("DefaultConnection"){}
        public DbSet<Meet> Meets { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```